# unable to boot into recovery mode

Tags: rooting

I have unlocked bootloader of my moto g3 6.0.1 and have installed the twrp recovery too but unable to boot into recovery mode. every time I make an attempt to open the twrp it shows no command on my device. I have tried many tWRP files... but  can't complete the process.

Comment: "No command" means you haven't flashed it in successfully. Check your flashing process, and optionally use `fastboot boot *filename_of_recovery.img*` instead to boot the recovery temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully flash the TWRP you must enter it **at the first time boot** after flashing. Otherwise it will be [overwritten by the standard recovery](http://mark.candleshoreblog.com/2013/06/13/tip-steps-to-prevent-clockwork-or-any-custom-recovery-from-being-overwritten-by-factory-stock-roms-at-android-system-reboot/) and all your efforts will be wasted. Also check [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110613/installed-cwm-twrp-but-it-isnt-installed-when-booting-to-recovery-mode).

Only first time matters.

Answer (score 0):

To properly flash TWRP on a Moto G 2015:

1) Unlock the bootloader via [Moto's official process](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a)
2) Copy the latest TWRP image from official [TWRP.me site](https://twrp.me/devices/motorolamotog2015.html) to your platform-tools directory if in Windows, or to your home directory if in Linux
3) Open a terminal window with administration/root privileges and navigate to the location of your twrp image file
4) In the terminal enter `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` (replace twrp.img with the actual filename from twrp.me)
5) DO NOT REBOOT - Immediately start Recovery, TWRP should start
6) When TWRP starts, it will prompt you "Keep System Read Only" then Swipe to Allow Modification
7) Select `Reboot` then `Recovery` then `Do Not Install`
8) The device will reboot and TWRP should load and will be "set" as your recovery from now on.

Note, although it is not essential, I do recommend performing a complete backup BEFORE flashing TWRP... TWRP can be booted without modifying the existing recovery or filesystem. Use the command `fastboot boot twrp.img` and select 'Do Not Modify` then perform a full backup to the SD card and archive it for future use if needed.